# How to find my server in LAN?

Tags: tcp, network-programming, ip, lan

I have two my own applications on C++ and Java: server and client. It both in one LAN and can transfer data via specified port. I want to make it possible, that client can find IP of server. But how to?
Enumeration of all possible IP with address mask - bad idea, it will take a lot of time. May be exists some way, where I can send broadcast to lan from client and receive it in server? Or another way... I can't find information about this, but I think that is possible, because I see it in MyPhoneExplorer on android, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using UDP broadcast?
the client can UDP broadcast "I am at x.x.x.x", and the server can answer (in UDP) to the client, "I am at y.y.y.y".

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use the [Broadcast Address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address) to find your server.