# Get clients on the network discover the server

Tags: java, tcp, client, ip

I'm currently writing a Java application that uses TCP/IP to communicate. What i'm trying to accomplish is to get the client to easy find the server and connect by sending some message out.

The question now is:
What can i do to make the client discover the server?

Is there a way i can send a message to the router (DHCP-server maybe) that tells it that I'm using this service? Then the client could check if there is anything like that on the router (DHCP-server) and connect to the appropriate IP.

Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: I think you can use some kind of broadcasting mechanism from the server. And, use a logic to capture these packets in the client.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find my server in LAN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520998/how-to-find-my-server-in-lan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UDP broadcast. Here [some details](http://michieldemey.be/blog/network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast/) about implementation.

Comment: Thank you, i'm gonna use this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [zeroconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking). It is a multicast-dns solution for service advertisement and discovery. The protocol was originally by Apple as the [bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29) protocol. There is also a popular open source implementation of the protocal called [Avahi](http://avahi.org/).

There is a java library [avahi4j](http://code.google.com/p/avahi4j/) which maybe helpful. I personally have no first hand experience with avahi4j but has used avahi for other non java projects.

Be aware that this approach will only work with the broadcast domain of the local sub-net.

Comment: Thanks, I think i'm just going to use valodzka's method since I have already started and it looks more straightforward :-) Thanks anyway !!