# How to retrieve server program ip by client program by only knowing the port number in a LAN?

Tags: c, winsock, winsock2

I am a rookie trying to learn winsock programming in c. Please tell me if the following is possible.
And sorry if the question is silly.But I really want to know the answer.

I am trying  a client program which can search the network for its relative server with only the specified port number . The client must find the IP which provides the service in that specified port and then retrieve that ip back to client program.All this in the same system or in a LAN.

one of my friends said that I must use the Multicast DNS or UDP in the first part of the client  to get the ip. After getting the ip then I could create the tcp connection with the server.

Is it really possible to send the clients ip to server through udp and initiate a tcp connection from the server to the client.
I have a basic idea what multicast DNS is.But I am not versed enough to use it in a live program.

Can anyone tell what winsock2 commands I must use for these operations?????
And sorry if I am being silly to your eyes.

Comment: If the machine in question only listens on this specific port using TCP, any UDP multicast does not help you here.

Comment: @alk is there any other way??

Comment: "*trying to learn winsock programming in C*" you perhaps better might like to start with some more trivial use case?

Comment: "*other way** scan through all possible IP addresses using a call to `connect()` on each? To reduce the number of addresses to test, you might assume that all addresses belong to the subnet the client machine belongs to.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14542226/694576

Comment: What sort of protocol the both are expected to speak in the end?

Comment: @alk I am trying your method of connecting to all possible ip's as we speak . If successful i will let you know . Thanks for the great hint friend

Answer (score 2):

> one of my friends said that I must use the Multicast DNS or UDP in the first part of the client to get the ip. After getting the ip then I could create the tcp connection with the server.

What your friend is referring to is typically implemented using a UDP subnet broadcast.  The client sends a UDP message to the LAN subnet's broadcast IP address on a specific port.  *IF* the server is on the same subnet as the client, and *IF* it is listening on that UDP port, it will receive the message and can send a response back to the client IP/port that sent the message.  When the client receives that response, it will know the server's IP and can then connect to the server's TCP port.

Another option is *IF* the server uses Multicast to broadcast its TCP IP/port periodically.  A client could join the multicast group, receive the broadcasted IP/port, and then connect to it.

> Is it really possible to send the clients ip to server through udp

Yes, by sending a UDP broadcast message to the entire subnet on a given port.  All machines listening on that UDP port will receive the same message, and can choose to either ignore it or respond to it.

> and initiate a tcp connection from the server to the client.

The client would still have to initiate the connection to the server.  The broadcast simply allows the client to discover the server's IP without having to hunt for it.

> Can anyone tell what winsock2 commands I must use for these operations?

*IF* the server can respond to a UDP broadcast, the client can use `sendto()` or `WSASendTo()` to send the broadcast, and then use `recvfrom()` or `WSARecvFrom()` to receive the response.  Use `GetAdaptersInfo()` or `GetAdaptersAddresses()` to discover the LAN's subnet broadcast IP address.  The broadcast port must be known ahead of time.

*IF* the server broadcasts its IP using multicast, the client can use `setsockopt(IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP)` or `setsockopt(MCAST_JOIN_GROUP)` to join the multicast group, and then use `recvfrom()` or `WSARecvFrom()` to receive the broadcasts.

Of course, in either approach, the actual format of the broadcast message(s) must be known ahead of time.

And *IF* the server does not support either approach, you will have to resort to a manual brute-force scan of the subnet.  Given the client's assigned IP address and subnet mask (again, obtainable from `GetAdaptersInfo()` or `GetAdaptersAddresses()`), you can easily calculate the first and last IP addresses of the subnet, and then connect to the TCP port on every IP address of the subnet until you find the server.

Comment: thanks for your great explanation. I will try all the methods specified. After i succeeded i will let you know which method i used.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, It is possible... 
See what you need to do is broadcast initial request(What should be the response , must be known to you.. Kinda like handshaking) in your network on that specific port. Now whichever device will respond that way you will know that..

Make server in such a way that for initial request it would reply with it's IP and details...

If you are in same LAN then only it is possible.

Comment: Broadcast a TCP connection request?

Comment: I assumed you took into account the comment(s) the OP gave.