# Windows CMD to find listening TCP/IP ports of a "un-ping-able" PC on LAN?

Tags: ip, port, ping, lan

I am developing a server-client web-application on LAN, in which the clients need to auto-detect & connect to the server.

Because some servers are with windows fiewall on, pinging them reply nothing. I wonder how can I detect that type of server PCs?

The only clue I have is that the Servers' application run on a random port in range : 1025 ~ 2025.

Do I need to try connecting from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.254 & check 1000 ports for every IP?
Thanks !

Comment: Servers should not run on a random port, unless you use a service like portmapper that provides a directory to find it (and that has to run on a known port). And you should use a server discovery protocol like Active Directory or Bonjour to find the server IP.

Comment: You could also try using Broadcast, as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520998/how-to-find-my-server-in-lan?rq=1

Comment: @Barmar : Thanks for your suggestion. I can make the server to be ping-able. Is that reliable if I find the server by the command "arp -a" instead of scanning all the IP range 192.168.0.1-254 ?

Comment: Ping and ARP have nothing to do with finding servers.

Comment: My currently approach is to find all available IPs on LAN and check if port 1025 is listening. Cause I don't know much about network, AD, UDP Broadcast and the likes... so, this might be my most feasible solution. Hmm

Comment: That's a silly way to do it. I told you some standard technologies that are used for applications like this, I suggest you take the time to research them.

Comment: @Barmar: OK. I know IPs in Lan are dynamic and it's not stable way to do. I'm learning UDP Broadcast. Thank you very much for your good advices. PS: Please write an answer for me to accept as solution.